# When to use critical sections and barriers in OMP?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, shared, critical-section, openmp

Do I have to use a critical section when reading data from a common vector/array from each thread? Could there be any conflicts?

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
// ...

using namespace std;

// ...

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    vector<double> data;
    // populating vector from a file, for example...

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
        // ...

        // in this cycle I only READ from the vector 'data'
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            for (vector<double>::iterator it = data.begin(); it < data.end(); it++)
            {
                double value = *it;
                // do some actions with 'value'...
            }
        }

        // ...
    }

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

I am afraid threads could work incorrectly when reading from the common (shared) vector. Am I right?

Comment: As long as no other thread modifies the data there should be no problem, unless you seriously want to optimize for caching/coalescence etc.

Comment: @demorge Thank you. I use critical sections anyway.

Comment: Using critical sections "anyway" will effectively serialize the operations within the inner pragma across all the threads executing code in the outer pragma. If the inner pragma represents a significant amount of the overall work then this will impact your perf. You only need to use a critical section if you have threads reading and writing in parallel to the same data.